# Syntax error with python & sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a syntax problem using sqlite3 with Python around the last line of the below code:

```
    playerName = input("Enter your name: ")
    money = input("Enter credits: ")
    conn = sqlite3.connect("highscore.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE players(name TEXT, money INTEGER)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO players VALUES('%s','%s')", playerName, money)
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO players VALUES('%s','%s')", playerName, money)
```

To:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO players VALUES(?,?);",(playerName, money))
```

Comment: I mean: c.execute("INSERT INTO players VALUES(?,?)",(playerName, money))

Comment: @user3283415 yes, you are right, and to avoid troubles later check my edit. And please mark the question as being answered.